# How to update new data in gridview?

Tags: c#

I have a form where data is entered and then it is saved in database table when i click Save button. In order to view the data I added, i need to close the form and then re open it. I tried these lines of code to refresh the gridview
dataGridView1.Refresh();
dataGridView1.Update();
but both of them are not working. Help me

Comment: you are probably saving the data to the database but you are not updating the collection you are binding the grid to.   When you click your Save Button try to update the collection with the data as well as save to database.

Comment: #mrsargent can u please guide me what i m doing wrong or what piece of code i should write?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly! - __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing.. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type, but when asking for help here is __not__ the time to be so lazy..! - Also add the code of both databinding/retrieval and updating, properly formatted! DGV.Refresh refreshes the display, not the data source and update does the update of the data (if it is set up correctly) not the display.

Comment: can you edit you post and copy the relevant code?

Comment: @mrsargent here is my code for c#

Comment: string query = @"insert into Course_teacher(CourseName , TeacherName , Semester) 
                           values(@CourseName , @TeacherName ,@Semester)";
            db.OpenConnection();
            db.com = new SqlCommand(query, db.con);
            db.com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName", textBox_CourseName.Text.Trim());
            db.com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeacherName", textBox_TeacherName.Text.Trim());
            db.com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Semester", comboBox_Semester.Text);

Comment: @TaW Sorry for incomplete question i asked.. i m using windows form c#..  and i tried this code
 private void button_refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
            dataGridView1.Update();
        }

Comment: can you add your code for how you retrieve data the data when your application starts and how you databind to the DataGridView? (i.e. set the DataSource property for the DataGridView?  Can you edit your original post and put the code in there instead of the comment section?  Makes it much easier to read.

Comment: @mrsargent i have no code for that.. i m very confused

Comment: check this out  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktQSLx3WfXA

Comment: Nobody wants to read __unformatted code in comments__. Please edit your question to make it complete and readable!

Comment: @mrsargent thankyou for the link. I need to ask what should i write in square bracket in this line of code   datagridview1.DataMember= ds.Tables[0].ToString();      [0] is written in video tutorial what should i write?

Comment: You set it to the name of the table in your datasource that you want to display.  If you have only 1 table you can ommit this property.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datamember(v=vs.110).aspx